# Python Weather-API Module - Errno 11001: getaddrinfo failed error

Tags: python-3.x

Recently I have come back to some code of mine, that used to work perfectly fine from the weather-api module (https://pypi.org/project/weather-api/). However now it just spits out a long error of which I'm not sure what to do with.

I have traced the error back to the weather.py, and tried artificially slowing down the request rate with time.sleep(), however to no avail.

```py
from weather import Weather , Unit
weather = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
location = weather.lookup_by_location('London')
```

This gives the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0398B1B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='query.yahooapis.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/public/yql?q=select*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text='London')%20and%20u='c'%20&format=json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0398B1B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    location = weather.lookup_by_location('London')
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\weather\weather.py", line 27, in lookup_by_location
    self.URL, location, self.unit)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\weather\weather.py", line 38, in _call
    def _call(self, url):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='query.yahooapis.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/public/yql?q=select*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text='London')%20and%20u='c'%20&format=json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0398B1B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Now trying to deconstruct the error I get to `D:\Program Files\Python\Lib\site-packages\weather\weather.py` at `Ln: 38` (in the `_call()` function) which looks like:

```py
def _call(self, url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    print('here') # my addition to the code. This is never reached.
    if self.log:
        self.logger.info("Request URL: %s" % req.url)
        self.logger.info("Status Code: %s" % req.status_code)
        self.logger.info("JSON Response: %s" % req.content)
    if not req.ok:
        req.raise_for_status()

    try:
        results = req.json()
        if self.log:
            self.logger.info(results)
        if int(results['query']['count']) > 0:
            wo = WeatherObject(results['query']['results']['channel'])
            return wo
        else:
            if self.log:
                self.logger.warn("No results found: %s " % results)
            return
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.warn(e)
        self.logger.warn(req.content)
        sys.exit(0)
```

I don't know why the requests module would cause this error, does anyone know a solution?

Expected outcome: a class object which should contain data from yahoo weather that can be read as a string with `location.text`.

Actual outcome: an error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo's weather API is deprecated! Who would've thought.

(Meaning trying to run `requests.get(url)` on the Yahoo url that no longer works didn't yield the correct results)